# C++ constructor problems

Tags: c++, class, constructor, return-type

I haven't used c++ for a long time and I never really did grasp classes too well.
I decided to relearn classes by making a small geometry app.
Here is square.h:

```
class Square{
public:
    float width;
    float height;
    float area;
    float perimeter;


    void Square(int,int);
    void Square();
    void ~Square();




};
```

Here is square.cpp:

```
#include "square.h"

Square::Square (int w, int h){
    width = w;
    height = h;
    area = width * height;
    perimeter = (width*2)+(height*2);
}

Square::Square (){

}

Square::~Square (){

}
```

When I run/build the program it says `error: return type specification for constructor invalid`
I guess this is saying the constructors and destructors should be something other than `void`, but I think I'm wrong.

Comment: Why are the constructor parameters ints when the width and height are stored as floats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I guess this is saying the constructors and destructors should be something other than `void`

Yes, it should be:

```
Square(int,int);
Square();
~Square();
```

> I thought `void` means the function doesn't return anything?

Yes, but these are not functions. They're constructors and destructors, which don't need a specified return type.

Comment: thank you! I thought `void` means the function doesn't return anything?

Comment: @Awalrod Yes, but they're not functions. They're constructors and destructors.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of `void` in constructors and destructor.

```
Square(int,int);
Square();
~Square();
```

And a suggestion since you are learning. If you are not thinking of exposing class variables to subclasses, make them private.

Answer (score 0):

In constructors and destructors there should be no return type at all,

```
class Square
{
public:
    float width;
    float height;
    float area;
    float perimeter;


    Square(int,int);
    Square();
    ~Square();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

`Constructor` and `destructor` have no return type. They are a special kind of function of class having the same name of the `class`.

```
class Square{
public:
    float width;
    float height;
    float area;
    float perimeter;


    Square(int,int);
    Square();
    ~Square();




};
```